# Is it possible to set up a screen loop in synergy 1.4?

Tags: synergy

In synergy 1.3 i was able to set up my screens such that the following was true:

```
|-> [Windows machine] <-> [Mac machine] <-|
|-----------------------------------------|
```

Thereby making it such that i can move my mouse in one horizontal direction indefinitely, as the mouse will just loop back on itself to the original screen. I was able to do this in Synergy 1.3 by stating in the config that my mac was both to the left and to the right of my windows machine.

I tried to replicate this in synergy 1.4.7 by making my config look like this:

```
[Mac computer][Windows server computer][Mac computer]
```

I cannot however seem to do this as the server on my windows box will not start if there are duplicate screens in the config. Is this sort of configuration possible in synergy 1.4? How would I go about configuring this if so? Do I have to manually edit the config file to do this?

**Why I want to do this, if you're curious:**

I want to do this because my current working environment is set up such that my mac laptop is connected to a monitor, but in between my laptop and second monitor is another monitor connected to my windows machine. I would normally swap which monitor is attached to which machine, but the majority of my work is done on my mac, and the monitor it is hooked up to is larger than the one hooked up to my windows one. furthermore, the monitors are mounted to the desk so i can't easily swap them. I could rearrange my desk to make it possible to put my macbook on the same side as my mac monitor, but having the ability to loop screens has proven valuable to me recently beyond simply making my current workspace intuitive to work in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need duplicate screens to do this - just be clever with your links.

```
section: links
  windows:
    left: mac
    right: mac
  mac:
    left: windows
    right: windows
end
```

Comment: right, but the standard GUI configuration doesn't allow me to do this, at least that's what i've found. This is essentially what I was able to do in synergy 1.3 but the GUI won't let me do this in 1.4.

Comment: I ended up manually editing the temporary config file created by synergy 1.4 to use those links though, and it works now. The configuration GUI could use an advanced mode similar to the old windows GUI from 1.3 IMO :)

Comment: Vim is the only config gui you ever need ;)

Comment: Is it possible to use non-temp config files if you have the synergy gui installed?